# Is X et al. one word or multiple words?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, difference, word-formation

as you know in in-text citation, we use this format to cite a reference of more than two authors. For example, if the first author's name is X, we write:

> As stated in X et al. [1], ...

Because this citation can be divided into multiple lines some times, I need to know if the sentence is one or multiple words? Because if it is one word, then I need to use the hyphen `-` if the word is broken into multiple lines. Otherwise, there is no need for the hyphenation.

Comment: I have never seen it hyphenated. Having said that, it would look odd getting _al_ at the start of a line, so perhaps a non-breaking space between "et" and "al" would  be good, if your software supports that. But that is a detail.

Comment: Would you insert a hyphen in "fish finger" if it were split over line ending? 99% of the time you should let the typesetter (TeX, Word, etc) do all the line splitting and hyphenation, because it is better at it than you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"et al." is an abbreviation of the latin phrase "[et alii](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/et_alii)" (meaning "and others"), which is two words ("et" and "alii"), so this should be treated as two words in English text as well.  Breaking the line between these words is fine, and it should not be hyphenated when broken across lines.

All of the rest of the words are just ordinary English words, so there is no need for special hyphenation with any of this.

Really, you only need to add a hyphen when breaking lines if you are breaking lines somewhere that does not already have a space.  Anywhere there is already a space (such as between "et" and "al.", or between the author's name and "et", etc.) you can break the line without needing to add a hyphen.  It doesn't really matter if they're "words" or not (though in general, any space is considered a "word separator" so if there's a space between two things, then they're generally going to be considered separate words).

Answer (score 0):

In academic texts, one uses: Smith et al. to refer to more than one author for an article or book.

Et al refers to other authors, not other words.

Here is a formal explanation of it:

[APA Style Guide](https://blog.apastyle.org/apastyle/2011/02/et-al-when-and-how.html)

1. Writers sometimes use the surname of the first author followed by et al. at the first mention of a work that has three, four, or five authors.  Only when a work has six or more authors should the first in-text citation consist of the first author followed by et al.  With five or fewer authors, all the author surnames should be spelled out at first mention.
2. Writers also make the opposite error by including all author surnames when et al. should be used instead.  Once an in-text citation has been mentioned one time, all subsequent citations to a work with three or more authors should consist of the surname of the first author followed by et al.

et al. - et alia, which means: and others in this context.